# Data source of English speech phrases

Tags: speech, phrases

I am doing a research on developing a simulated environment for the students (who use English as second language) to practice English speaking.

In one part of my development, **I need a data source which contains mostly using English speech phrases which are tagged against the real incident.** As an exmaple,
“Ways to Apologise
Sorry.
I’m sorry.
I’m so sorry!
Sorry for your loss.”

I could find several sites which are providing this service http://edition.englishclub.com, but not a data source.

Has somebody used such a data source , which can be used like ‘wordnet’ ? If so please help me to carry on this forward. Otherwise I have to develop such a data source which I feel like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Can you clarify "which are tagged against the real incident?" Do you mean "tagged with their meaning?"